# If there are 29 vehicles per one square kilometers, how many square kilometers per 100 vehicles are there?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, dimensional-analysis

29 vehicles/$km^2$ means (1/29) $km^2$/(1 vehicle)

Per 100 vehicles there are 1/2900 $km^2$.

Whatever you sq kilometers are you have to divide by 100 moto vehicles

100/29 $km^2$/100 vehicles

(100/29)/100=1/29

Why is the wrong?

The other way is if you have more vehicles, you add up the $km^2$ each has, so you multiple (1/29) by 100.

Comment: If you have $\frac1{29}\,\text{km}^2/\text{vehicle}$ then you have $100$ times this in $\frac{100}{29}\,\text{km}^2/\text{100 vehicles}$.  If you cancel the $100$s then you get straight back to  $\frac1{29}\,\text{km}^2/\text{vehicle}$

Comment: How did you conclude that "per 100 vehicles there are 1/2900 $km^2$"?

Comment: Use ratios. We get $\frac{29}{1}=\frac{100}{x}\implies x=\frac{100}{29}$.